# Nginx returns 404 When I use valid_referers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, next.js

This is my environment:

- Rails
- Axios
- Next.js
- AWS EC2
- Nginx
- Vercel

I have two domains in production environment.

One is let's say `fuga.com` which is made with rails and containing some front pages.

Another one is `hoge.com` which is made with next.js.

`hoge.com` usually fetch data from `fuga.com` using http request.

But if I access to let's say `fuga.com/users_data` using browser I would see all users data.

Because api is global?

Anyway It's really bad in terms of security.

So I came up with blocking all domains aside from `hoge.com`.
I configured in nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name fuga.com hoge.com;
    root /var/www/xxx/current/public;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://xxx;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
    # ↓here↓
    location /admin {
      valid_referers none blocked server_names hoge\.com;
      if ($invalid_referer) { return 403; }
    }

}
```

I want to block all domains `/admin/~` aside from `hoge.com`.

So I used `valid_referers none blocked`.

From my search, it's white list which can only access.

But I got this parameter from access log in nginx:

```
172.31.xx.xxx - - [10/May/2022:13:31:58 +0000] "POST /admin/auth/sign_in/ HTTP/1.1" 404 188 "https://hoge.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/xxx.0.xxxx.54 Safari/xxx.36" "106.xx.xx.xxx" "-"
```

status code is `404`.

So I tried `allow` instead of `valid_referers` like:

```
...
    location /admin {
      allow 172.xx.xx.xxx;
      deny all;
    }
```

But nginx returns:

```
172.xx.x.xxx - - [10/May/2022:13:34:12 +0000] "POST /admin/auth/sign_in/ HTTP/1.1" 403 187 "https://hoge.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/xxx.x.xxxx.54 Safari/xxx.xx" "xxx.xx.xx.xxx" "-"
```

I can't understand what's going on...

I'm sure It's completely problem of nginx setting.

Because if I remove `allow` and `valid_referers` it would work fine.

How can I fix the problem..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every request ends up in a particular location and uses that location *content handler*. You can't do something like

```
location / {
    ... some settings ruleset
}
location /admin {
    ... additional settings ruleset
}
```

and expect that `/admin/...` request would use a combined settings ruleset. Your first locations uses an `http_proxy_module` content handler declared with the `proxy_pass` directive (other content handlers directive examples are `fastcgi_pass`, `uwsgi_pass`, etc.). Since there is no any content handler explicitly declared in your second location, nginx will use a *static content handler* for the requests handled with that location (in other words, will try to serve a request with some local file), and since such a local file does not exists, gives you an HTTP `404 Not Found` response. You can either duplicate your main location content with your second location (not the best way) or use some other solution like `map` block:

```
map $uri $deny {
    ~^/admin  $invalid_referer;
    # default value will be an empty string, so we can omit "default '';" here
}
server {
    ...
    location / {
        if ($deny) { return 403; }
        ... rest of the configuration
    }
}
```

Comment: ohh..!! Tank you! I'll try it!